# How do i make <h3> at the same height

Tags: html, css

[I got h3 tags. One is lower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izslY.png)
I tried using margin: 0 and padding but it didn't worked and i don't know what is wrong.

After deleting align-items: center it fixed the height but how to make it in center of container on picture without breaking height of h3
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dst9.png)

```css
.info-footer {
  background-color: rgba(33, 40, 59, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(53, 56, 72);
  width: 100%;
  height: 14em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 200px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  align-items:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-footer">
  <div class="info-footer-info">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Regulamin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Polityka Prywatności</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="info-footer-menu">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are specifying that they need to be vertically aligned in the middle with `align-items: center`. If that's not the desired behaviour, change the value to something else (e.g. `flex-start`) or remove it altogether.

Comment: Would you mind being more specific? Because the image you supplied doesn't make sense with your question, do you mean that h3 should be aligned on top or that it should be the same height as `ul`?

Comment: I want the h3 tags at the same height

Comment: Please do not modify your question in such a way that the original context is lost.

Comment: @AlexIK____ I don't fully understand what you mean. Do you want the `li` items to be lower down or more to the left?

Answer (score 0):

remove `align-items: center;` from `.info-footer` style.

What `align-items` does is:

> Aligns flex items along the cross axis of the current line of the flex container.

Choosing `center` means it places the elements to the center of the `flex` container and works its way around that. In other words, your `footer-info` and `footer-menu` are aligned to the **center** of the flex container rather than the **start**.

```css
.info-footer {
  background-color: rgba(33, 40, 59, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(53, 56, 72);
  width: 100%;
  height: 14em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 200px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-footer">
  <div class="info-footer-info">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Regulamin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Polityka Prywatności</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="info-footer-menu">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to achive what you want with being able to center the info you can wrap them inside another div so the `align-items` won't effect them

```css
.info-footer {
      background-color: rgba(33, 40, 59, 0.8);
      color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid rgb(53, 56, 72);
      width: 100%;
      height: 14em;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 200px;
      padding: 20px 10px;
      align-items:center;
 }
.info-footer-box{
    display: flex;
 }
```

```html
    

    <div class="info-footer">
      <div class="info-footer-box">
        <div class="info-footer-info">
          <h3>Menu 1</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Regulamin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Polityka Prywatności</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="info-footer-menu">
          <h3>Menu 2</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

change align-items:center to align-items:start and wrap everything in a container.  Give height of 100vh to the container and use flex again

```css
.info-footer {
  background-color: rgba(33, 40, 59, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 200px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  align-items: start;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

body,div,html{
margin:0;
padding:0;}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class="info-footer">
    <div class="info-footer-info">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Regulamin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Polityka Prywatności</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="info-footer-menu">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `top` is not a valid value for `align-items`. It happens to work in this case just because the default is `stretch`.

Comment: look at new picture please

Answer (score -2):

Always use the appropriate HTML tags. CSS flex will align these for you.

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section>
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Regulamin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Polityka Prywatności</a></li>
      </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: Then how can I align them in center because if I use align items center the h3 tag will go down

Comment: `justify-content: center;` Here's a flex playground / interactive demo https://ronnieroyston.com/tools/css-flexbox